# javascript add value month

Tags: javascript, html, date

I'm creating a system and I need to add a value on a variable every month. For example, Last January I have 5 vacation leaves and every month I need to add 1 leave. A breakdown would be something like this:
January = 5 leaves
February = 6 leaves (I used up 2 leaves during this month, leaving me with 4 leaves)
March = 5 leaves
April = 6 leaves
so on and so forth.

What approach or how will I able to accomplish it?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Sounds like you want to store it somewhere? Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just the calculation, then you can add months by doing `d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1)`. This makes *Date* do all the messy stuff of working out how long each month is.

```
var initial_value = 5,
    initial_date = new Date(2014, 0, 1), // January
    end_date = new Date(2014, 3, 1);     // April

var spent = 2;

var value = initial_value,
    date = new Date(initial_date);
while (date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1), date <= end_date)
    value += 1;

value -= spent;

value; // 6
```

---

This method is good for days of month `< 29`, for days `29 <= x <= 31` you will need additional checks
i.e. check how many months it changed by then if not `1`, what behaviour do you want in those cases?

---

If you always want the last day of the month, then it's only a couple steps longer than above,

```
d.setDate(1);                 // go to a "safe day" to change months
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 2); // go 2 months forward
d.setDate(0);                 // roll back to the last day of the previous month
```

---

Something extra I've been playing with

```
var dates = (function () {
    function isLeapYear(year) {
        if (year % 4)   // not divisible by 4
            return false;
        if (year % 100) // not divisible by 100
            return true;
        if (year % 400) // not divisible by 400
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    return {
        year: new Date().getUTCFullYear(),
        get leapYear() { return isLeapYear(this.year); },
        isLeapYear: isLeapYear,
        get total() { return 365 + isLeapYear(this.year); },
        0: 31,
        get 1() { return 28 + isLeapYear(this.year); },
        2: 31,
        3: 30,
        4: 31,
        5: 30,
        6: 31,
        7: 31,
        8: 30,
        9: 31,
        10: 30,
        11: 31
    };
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, what I want to achieve is to add 1 on initial_value every month. Sorry, if I was confusing. Let's say the initial_value is 5, after 10 months, it should be 15.

Comment: `This makes Date do all the messy stuff of working out how long each month is`. Not in all cases: use the above method to add one month to 31 May. You'll get 1 July.

Comment: @RobG That's true, and that that is the correct value even if you tried to "add one" to the month number anyway, because there is no _31st of June_. It's also why I used the first of each month in the code.

Comment: @user3545006 if you're starting from the `x >= 29`th day of each month, you may wish to add in another check so you can correct when days overflow the length of months

Comment: Getting the days in the month can be a lot less code: `function getDaysInMonth(m, y) {return ((!(y % 4) && y % 100) || !(y % 400) && m == 2)? 29 : [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31][--m];}`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use this when adding months to a date and I don't want to overflow the month:

```
function addMonthsNoOverflow(dateParam, intParam) {
    var sum = new Date(new Date(dateParam.getTime()).setMonth(dateParam.getMonth() + intParam);
    if (sum.getDate() < dateParam.getDate()) {  sum.setDate(0);  }
    return(sum);
}
```

Notes:

It handles cases where 29, 30 or 31 turned into 1, 2, or 3 by eliminating the overflow

Day of Month is NOT zero-indexed so .setDate(0) is last day of prior month.